# Errors in implementing an integral function from x to infinity from scratch in CPP with substitution

Tags: c++, math, calculus

So I am trying to implement an integration function from scratch in CPP. I have been stuck on this for 2 days.

I am not sure how to do an integration computation from x to +inf. My plan was to use the sigmoid function as a substitution for the integration which should mathematically work but it didn't work computationally. Formula reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals

My questions are 1). why my method didn't work? 2). Is there a better method/function to be used for the substitution?

**Reproducible Code**
which can be accessed via https://onlinegdb.com/F3rzIEReA with explanations as comments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

using namespace std;


// I have an interface for a real function named RealFunction which
// is used to be fed into the integral function
class RealFunction {
    public:
        virtual ~RealFunction() {};
        virtual double evaluate( double x ) = 0;
};

// integral function that utilises the rectangular rule
double integral( RealFunction& f,
                 double a,
                 double b,
                 int nPoints ) {
    double h = (b-a)/nPoints;
    double x = a + 0.5*h;
    double totalHeight = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<nPoints; i++) {
        double height = f.evaluate(x);
        totalHeight+=height;
        x+=h;
    }
    return h*totalHeight;
}

// a probability normal distribution function
class NormPDF : public RealFunction {
    public:
        NormPDF(double mu, double sigma) :
                mu(mu), sigma(sigma){}
        NormPDF() :
                mu(0.0), sigma(1.0){}
        double mu;
        double sigma;

        double evaluate(double x){
                return exp(-0.5*pow((x-mu)/sigma,2.0))/(sigma*sqrt(2*PI));
}
};

// my chosen substitution function - sigmoid function
double sigmoidFunction(double x) {
    return 1/(1+exp(-x));
}

// implementing the integral to infinity function with
// the sigmoid function
double integralToInfinity( RealFunction& f,
                        double x,
                        int nPoints) {

    class SigmoidInfusedFunction : public RealFunction {
        public:
            SigmoidInfusedFunction(RealFunction& f) :
                f(f) {
            }

            RealFunction &f;
            double evaluate(double x) {
                // d(sig)/dx = exp(-x) / pow(1+exp(-x),2)
                return f.evaluate(sigmoidFunction(x)) * exp(-x) / pow(1+exp(-x),2);
            }
    };
    SigmoidInfusedFunction sigmoidInfusedFunc(f);
    return integral(sigmoidInfusedFunc, sigmoidFunction(x), 1, 1000);
}


int main() {

    // Test for integrate - result: 0.95004 expected: 0.95 (CORRECT)
    NormPDF normPDF;
    cout << integral(normPDF, -1.96, 1.96, 1000) << endl;
    
    // Test for infinity - result: 0.0688965 expected: 0.5 (INCORRECT)
    cout << integralToInfinity(normPDF, 0, 1000) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [example], representative input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia link you cited is for definite integrals.  If the upper bound is infinity, that's not a definite integral.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Wrong. It is still *definite* integral. Indefinite integral does not have bounds.

Comment: @seel  How do you deal wirh with infinite value of integral? WHat about integral from -pi to pi of tan(x)?

Comment: It's been a long time since I studied this kind of calculus, but... don't you have the limits wrong? If you're trying to integrate **f** from **s** to **t** using a function **p,** then you must choose limits **a** and **b** such that **s = p(a)** and **t = p(b).** But you're setting **a = p(s)** and **b = p(t).** To be specific, **a = S(0) = 1/2** and **b = S(infinity) = 1.** (To do it correctly with sigmoid, you must find **S(b) = infinity,** which doesn't exist; either I've made a serious error, or the sigmoid function won't work here.)